# Reusing a chain of Stream Operations

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm looking for a readable way to reuse a chain of stream operations.

The idea is that I have a certain sequence of actions that I want to apply to several streams in between other operations. The other operations are not identical between streams.

So, for example, for every stream, I want to change the case of a String, trim it, nullify empty Strings and then filter out nulls, and lastly, eliminate duplicates, like this:

In both cases, I do this sequence of actions:

```
.map( String::trim ).map( Strings::emptyToNull ).filter( Objects::nonNull ).distinct()
```

I currently duplicate that chain and put it between other actions for multiple streams:

```
myStream1.doSomeStuff().map( String::trim ).map( Strings::emptyToNull ).filter( Objects::nonNull ).distinct().doOtherStuff();

myStream2.doSomethingElse().map( String::trim ).map( Strings::emptyToNull ).filter( Objects::nonNull ).distinct().doSomethingElseStill();
```

Is there a good way to avoid rewriting that piece of code?
Obviously, it's possible for the two map() actions, but is there a way for this combination of actions?

Comment: Write a method that takes and returns a stream.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could wrap your `Stream<String>` in a function

```
public Stream<String> trimAndFilterOutEmptyStringsAndGetDistinctElements(Stream<String> stream) {
    return stream.map(String::trim)
                 .map(Strings::emptyToNull) // or use not(String::isEmpty) like suggested below
                 .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                 .distinct();
}
```

Which could be used like this

```
Stream<String> myStream1DownStream = trimAndFilterOutEmptyStringsAndGetDistinctElements(myStream1);
Stream<String> myStream2DownStream = trimAndFilterOutEmptyStringsAndGetDistinctElements(myStream2);

myStream1DownStream.doOtherStuff();
myStream2DownStream.doSomethingElseStill();
```

---

BTW I'd use

```
.filter(Predicate.not(String::isEmpty))
```

instead of

```
.map(Strings::emptyToNull)
.filter(Objects::nonNull)
```

---

There is a more questionnable way, it is to use Lombok's [`@ExtensionMethod`](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/ExtensionMethod) experimental feature. **I would not use it in production**

You'll then be able to extend the functionalities of the `Stream` class with custom methods

```java
public class Extensions {
    public static Stream<String> trimAndFilterOutEmptyStringsAndGetDistinctElements(Stream<String> stream) {
        return stream.map(String::trim)
                     .map(Strings::emptyToNull) // or use not(String::isEmpty) like suggested
                     .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                     .distinct();    
    }
}
```

The usage is the following

```
myStream1.trimAndFilterOutEmptyStringsAndGetDistinctElements()
         .doOtherStuff();
```

More info

- [`@ExtensionMethod`](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/ExtensionMethod)
- [Example from my blog](http://www.yassinhajaj.com/006-kotlin-sugar/kotlin-sugar/)

Comment: The reason I did not want to do that is readability. when using streams, one big perk is that you have a readable chain of interaction. By wrapping it in a function like this, I have to put the function around the first steps and therefore it's written first.
I.e. I will have:
```cleanUp(myStream1.doSomeStuff()).doOtherStuff();)```
where I would like something like:
```myStream1.doSomeStuff().cleanUp().doOtherStuff();)```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, Stream API is not designed to be extended.

Comment: There is a very questonnable way to extend it BTW, but I wouldn't do it in production.. I modified my post to add it

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, that's what I suspected, just was unable to find anything on it. The extension road is tempting, but I'll not go it for the little advantage in readability.